# Easy Install Astropysics gives Errors when transforming Coordinates, coordsys

Tags: python, astropy

I have some code that I wrote and imported to a new computer, I tried to do easy_install on astropysics and networkx but it seems that my previous (working) code has trouble with the easy_install version of astropysics. I've not seen this one before so I thought maybe someone here would have an idea. My relevant code is:

```
import os, sys
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import asciitable
from scipy import stats
import astropysics
import astropysics.obstools
import astropysics.coords
import math
import pylab as P
import random
from random import randint
from pylab import *
from astropysics.coords import ICRSCoordinates,GalacticCoordinates
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

f=open(sys.argv[1])
y= asciitable.read(f,Reader=asciitable.CommentedHeader,delimiter=' ')
f.close()

vhc = y['Vhelavg'] 
verr = y['Verravg']
Radeg=y['Radeg']
Decdeg=y['Decdeg']
Rcoeff=y['Rcoeffavg']
logg=y['loggavg']

vhcgood= (vhc != -99.9) & (vhc >= -400) & (vhc <= 400) & (logg<=2.3)
vhcg=vhc[vhcgood]

l=[]
b=[]
Radg=Radeg[vhcgood]
Decdg=Decdeg[vhcgood]
for i in xrange(len(Radg)):
gcoords=ICRSCoordinates(Radg[i],Decdg[i]).convert(GalacticCoordinates)
l.append(gcoords.l.radians)
b.append(gcoords.b.radians)
```

The Error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "gauss01_15.py", line 46, in <module>
gcoords=ICRSCoordinates(Radg[i],Decdg[i]).convert(GalacticCoordinates)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Astropysics-1.0-py2.7.egg/astropysics/coords/coordsys.py", line 1895, in convert
res = EpochalLatLongCoordinates.convert(self,tosys,optimize)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Astropysics-1.0-py2.7.egg/astropysics/coords/coordsys.py", line 1781, in convert
res = LatLongCoordinates.convert(self,tosys,optimize)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Astropysics-1.0-py2.7.egg/astropysics/coords/coordsys.py", line 1728, in convert
return CoordinateSystem.convert(self,tosys)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Astropysics-1.0-py2.7.egg/astropysics/coords/coordsys.py", line 1098, in convert
convpath = CoordinateSystem.getTransformPath(self.__class__,tosys)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Astropysics-1.0-py2.7.egg/astropysics/coords/coordsys.py", line 1038, in getTransformPath
path = nx.shortest_path(g,fromsys,tosys,weighted=True)
TypeError: shortest_path() got an unexpected keyword argument 'weighted'
```

I've never gotten this before and never had any issues with the simple python coordinate transform in astropysics. Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: What version of `networkx` do you have installed?

Comment: Also keep in mind that ["Astropysics is now in "maintainence mode" only."](https://github.com/eteq/astropysics#astropysics); you may want to change your script to use astropy instead (no fun, but it looks like for the above code, this is straightforward. You could then also replace `asciitable.read` with `astropy.table.Table.read(...)`.

Comment: Short version: use pip, don't use easy_install.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to upgrade your `astropysics` version. There was a change in the `networkx` (`nx`) dependency of `astropysics`, that has been taken care of in more recent version of `astropysics`. (The keyword argument `weighted` changed to `weight`, and apparently you have incompatible versions of `astropysics` and `networkx` to handle this change.)
The relevant fix is show in [these lines](https://github.com/eteq/astropysics/blob/master/astropysics/coords/coordsys.py#L1035) in astropysics.

You probably want to upgrade the `networkx` package as well, if that doesn't happen automatically for you.

```
easy_install --upgrade astropysics
easy_install --upgrade networkx
```

hopefully does it for you.

Comment: That is very confusing to type, "astropysics". Python-fun name aren't always convenient.

Comment: easy_install is all but deprecated. This should be saying "pip install --upgrade". I think the use of easy_install is at least part of the OP's problem, since it does not uninstall old packages before installing new ones, and can lead to inconsistencies in dependencies.